# Kafka Stream stops receiving messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Stream running with version `0.10.2.0`. All looked good until the stream simply stopped receiving new messages.

The stream state is `RUNNING` and there are no exceptions in the logs. Using [this FAQ entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Myconsumerseemstohavestopped,why?) I checked the lag and it is increasing.

My configuration looks like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG,
              CustomTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, streamName);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, streamName);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, myConfig.getBrokerList());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, myConfig.getCommitIntervalMs()); // 5000
    props.put(StreamsConfig.METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL_CONFIG, "DEBUG");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, myConfig.getStreamThreadsCount()); // 1
    props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, myConfig.getMaxCacheBytes()); // 524_288_000L
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50);
```

Looking at the JMX metrics, the threads are there and running, just not doing anything... The instance is still stuck so I may be able to check extra things if needed. Any help is appreciated

**EDIT (more info)**

When I execute `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker` the `owner` column says "none"

**EDIT 2**

On a stalled instance I see threads named "pool-X-thread-Y" in "Park" state. A healthy instance does not exhibit the same behavior.

**EDIT 3**

I found a very interesting piece of information, the metric `consumer-coordinator-metrics > heartbeat-response-time-max` (The max time taken to receive a response to a heartbeat request) reads 43,361 seconds (almost 12 hours) which is consistent with the time of the hang. Shouldn't this trigger a failure somehow?

Comment: Is only the lag is increasing because more data is appended than consumed, or do the committed offsets not increase at all?

Comment: The committed offsets do not increase at all, so according to the FAQ the app is stuck, not slow right?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax also worth noting, when I execute `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker` the `owner` column says "none"

Comment: @Hartimer: IIRC the `ConsumerOffsetChecker` works only for old, ZK-based Kafka consumers.  Kafka Streams uses Kafka's "new" consumer client, which stores its consumer offsets in Kafka, not in ZK.

Comment: Ok, still, based on the metrics it was consuming 0 messages. See the extra edits I made too

Comment: Did you check the offsets with `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` script? This should give you the committed offset and consumer group. Not sure what "pool-X-thread-Y" is... If the Streams internal consumer does not commit any offsets, you should see at least a warn message "log.warn("{} Failed to commit {} {} state: {}", logPrefix, task.getClass().getSimpleName(), task.id(), e);" -- but Streams will continue to process. Do you see any output written to your result topics? What's your log level? Maybe DEGUB (or TRACE?) might revile something...